# Wpf Datagrid not show one column while binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatable

While trying to bind a `DataTable` in WPF, The *First Column* values not shown in `DataGrid`.

`Code`

```
private DataTable _dt;

public DataTable DataTable
{
    get { return _dt; }
    set { _dt = value; }
}

public Controls()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _dt = new DataTable("Table");
    _dt.Columns.Add("S.No");
    _dt.Columns.Add("Name");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        _dt.Rows.Add(""+i, "Name "+ i);
    }

    dataGrid1.DataContext = _dt;                
}
```

`XAML`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          Height="131" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"              
          Name="dataGrid1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="359" />
```

[image: Output missing Serial Number in DataGrid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the column can not contain a dot or a space character, `DataBinding` does not support dots in сolumn names. This will not work across the board, not just in DataGrid `AutoGenerateColumns` but everywhere in the binding system.

Try changing `S.No` to just read `No` as the following code shows:

```
_dt = new DataTable("Table");
_dt.Columns.Add("No");
_dt.Columns.Add("Name");

DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    _dt.Rows.Add(""+i, "Name "+ i);                
}

dataGrid1.DataContext = _dt;
```

Comment: Your Information is little bit wrong, DataGrid column name accept the Dot Character - see the OP screen short. But the problem is column data binding. that's why i suggest to change the Column name in previous Answer. Change your information, bzs it confuse OP and others.

Comment: @RajaRaja Cholan: Yes, the point can be in the name of the column, I myself have tried, just WPF DataBinding engine doesn't support dots in DataColumn name. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: excelent, I give +1 for a complete solution. :-)

Comment: The same applies to using a '/' character (e.g., "Date/Time" does not work as a column name.  Use "DateTime" instead).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `_dt.Columns.Add("S.No");` to `_dt.Columns.Add("S_No");` or`_dt.Columns.Add("S-No");`.